# using the command line TFS client

Tags: tfs, command-line-interface, tf-cli

I'm trying to use the TFS command line client ([tf.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).  When I run 'tf get someProject' it hangs, and then says 'All files are up to date'.  Nothing is downloaded.  How can I get files from TFS using the command line client?  Thanks,

213897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `/recursive` switch to tell TFS to get everything in the Team Project? If you are then it sounds like TFS thinks that you already have the latest version in your local workspace. If you know this is incorrect you can use `/force` switch which tells TFS to ignore what it thinks is in the workspace and get everything (this will take a while if you have a large codebase and / or lots of branches)

Comment: well I'm unsure how to tell it what project to get too.  say I wanted 'someProject', if I didn't have a workspace set up I'd do 'tf workspace /new' from the directory I wanted to set up the workspace in and then 'tf get someProject /recursive' to download it?

Comment: I create a couple of batch files in the path.  One called tu.bat with tf get . /r which does an update.  The other is ts.bat with tf status . /r to output status update.

Comment: You can also do this in Powershell with 
function TfsStatus() { tf status . /r } 
function TfsUpdate() { tf get . /r } 
set-alias ts TfsStatus
set-alias tu TfsUpdate

Comment: I did that, but `tf get someProject /recursive` just made the directory folder, and didn't populate the folder.  Doing `tf get someProject /recursive /force` outputs 'Replacing someProject' and doesn't populate the folder

Comment: in this context what is "someProject" you need to give tf a tfs path e.g. tf get $/myTeamProject/devBranch/source/mySolution/ /recursive

Comment: odd, the full path downloads everything with the `/force /recursive` options where using only the project name simply makes the directory structure,  cheers,